# Runtime Error in Returning vector of vector from Level Order Traversal of binary tree

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, graph, tree, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, return the level order traversal of its nodes values, but we need to return a 2D integer array denoting the level order traversal of the given binary tree.
I tried to approach this as normal level order traversal but after each level put a NULL so that it will signify the new level in tree. If we encounter NULL in queue (using queue implementation) then it signifies that this level is completed so, we'll push NULL in queue. Below is my code -

```
vector<vector<int> > Solution::levelOrder(TreeNode* A) {
    queue<TreeNode*>q;
    q.push(A);
    q.push(NULL);
    vector<int>v;
    vector<vector<int>>ans;
    while(!q.empty()){
        TreeNode* temp = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(temp==NULL){
            q.push(NULL);
            ans.push_back(v);
            v.clear();
        }
        else{
            v.push_back(temp->val);
            if(temp->left!=NULL)
                q.push(temp->left);
            if(temp->right !=NULL)
                q.push(temp->right);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

I'm getting runtime error but unable to understand why ?

Comment: *I'm getting runtime error but unable to understand why ?* "Understanding why* means one thing -- debug your code.  Probably that's the main reason why you're being downvoted.  A simple two or three-level tree and use of the debugger would show the issue to you.

Comment: As the answer indicates, see what happens if you have a single node tree (you don't even need 2 or more levels).  You will see that you will just keep pushing NULL onto the queue in an infinite loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other issues in this code, but I'd like to focus on this bit:

```
if (temp == NULL) {
    q.push(NULL);
    ans.push_back(v);
    v.clear();
}
```

This means that if you pull a null pointer out of your queue, then you place a null pointer back into the queue and make `ans` bigger. But this means that your queue will never be empty, since every time you pull out the null sentinel you've added in you'll put it back, and `ans` will continue to grow until you run out of memory.

See if you can find another way of determining when a particular level in the tree ends.